# Jenkins two post-build actions but only one with git_commit

Tags: jenkins, queue, gitlab

In "Post-build Actions", I want to have first build that triggers without ${GIT_COMMIT} (e2e automation) but once that e2e automation is complete, I want to start second build that's triggered using ${GIT_COMMIT} ONLY if first build is stable.

Is there a way to put that into a queue.

A is Main code repo (alpha to beta)
B is e2e test repo (outside of A)
C is Main code repo (beta to gamma)

Currently it's set up so...
When A is stable, trigger B without ${GIT_COMMIT} (since B doesn't recognize ${GIT_COMMIT}) then when B is stable trigger C but C requires ${GIT_COMMIT}.

Is there a way for me to send in ${GIT_COMMIT} to B without having it build master branch instead of ${GIT_COMMIT}?
OR
Within A job, trigger B without ${GIT_COMMIT} then only when B is stable, trigger C with ${GIT_COMMIT} inside 'Post-build Actions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just storing it in a parameter that is not called GIT_COMMIT and use it in B and C? It costs nothing to send a pre-defined parameter called A_commitHash to B, and then to C.

Another way if you don't want to send parameters between jobs - run batch `echo A_commit=%GIT_COMMIT% >a.properties` and archive it in A. Then in C you can [copy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) it to the workspace and [inject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) it, making you able to use A_commit in your job.